# JSF: Backing Beans with nested objects?

Tags: java, jsf, class, nested, mbeans

**JSF 1.1**, using a backing bean with a nested objects inside I can read all properties of the nested object.

For example assuming a backing bean named "foo" with a nested object "bar" can I set/write via h:form all the properties of foo.bar?

I mean something like this:

```
            f:view
            h:form
            h:inputText value="#{myBean.mySelectedReport.someProp}" /
```

and this in the backing bean:

```
        public SomeObject getMySelectedReport() {...}
```

but when I sent it to the correct backing bean it doesn't store the value of the someProp value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Nice, I can answer by myself as I solved by myself**: 
if useful for others having the same problem the problem is the JSF 1.1 wildcard on "from-view-id", for example "/ajax/uiChannel*" match only pages without any query params into the "from url",
only this one "/ajax/uiChannel.jsp?*" and "/ajax/uiChannel*?*" wildcard seems to work